# Expect not submit form, however a linkbutton or another button except submit button perform a submit form

Tags: c#, asp.net

Expect not submit form, however a linkbutton or another button except submit button perform a submit form

no matter i use onclientclick, no response when use onclick event to window.open with javascript

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="StartApplicationLink" Text="Start your application" runat="server"  
                            TabIndex="7" OnClientClick="window.open('http://www.hello.com/register.aspx','_top','Asia - Registration');" class="button btn-red"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the form to submit, you got to return false on the `OnClientClick`

Something like this

```
OnClientClick = "window.open('http://www.hello.com/register.aspx',
                             '_top',
                             'Spring Asia - Registration'); return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to `return false` on OnClientClick event as below:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="StartApplicationLink" Text="Start your application" runat="server"  
                            TabIndex="7" OnClientClick="window.open('http://www.hello.com/register.aspx','_top','Asia - Registration');return false;" class="button btn-red"/>
```

return false will prevent the form to get submitted.